# How can I fit a glass cooktop hood into a space that's too tight?

Tags: glass, sanding, hood

I have just purchased a new glass cooker hood which is 600mm wide. The gap I have for it is also 600mm wide, though perhaps 599.9mm as it is currently a very snug fit. I am a little worried that the glass will break!

[image: The gap available for the new cooker hood]
*The gap available for the new cooker hood*

I cannot move the cupboards. How do I remove a small amount of glass from the new cooker hood so that it fits well, rather than tightly?

Comment: Please post photos of the wider area. The answer is not in the one you've shown us.

Comment: What does a **rubber mallet** have to say about moving the cabinets *point one millimeter* ?

Comment: I'd suggest you contact the supplier and see what they can do to help you swap your oversized item for a slightly smaller one.

Comment: Picture of the hood, please.  Most glass hoods I've seen *would* sand to fit.

Comment: Also, measure the front and back of the gap at the right height - it may be that once you've got the front in all will be well, and then it would just be the wood that bends.  OTOH it might be worse at the back where there's more structure in the cupboards to resist bending

Comment: Whatever you put there is going to heat up and be subject to thermal expansion, so a small gap is needed as thermal expansion forces are high. I guess that you could fill the gap with flexible, non-flammable material.

Comment: PIc of the hood or link to it?

Comment: Why not use a router and chisel to put a small groove in the cupboards?

Comment: As @AndrewMorton has started to point out - also consider steam will cause the cupboards to possibly expand too. This would only ever happen when you had the lid up.... which wouldn't end nicely I imagine.

Comment: @AndrewMorton *subject to thermal expansion* - incredibly unlikely to make any difference at all. By the time you'd heated an e.g. pyrex hood to the point where there was any risk of it being damaged by neighboring things, the house would be well on the way to being burnt down

Comment: @CaiusJard I expect the wood would have enough give in it to take up the expansion, even if the parts started out butted together, but why take the chance of shattered glass being dropped into hot oil when that could be designed out?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Glass does not take well to sanding, cutting, etc. It *can* be done, but not so easily. It is even harder on an assembled large object, as opposed to large flat sheets.

On the other hand, wood and similar materials (e.g., products made from various combinations of wood fibers, glue, etc.) can handle sanding very well, with minimal loss of strength and virtually no chance of sudden failure. A crack in glass will almost inevitably lead to structural failure. A crack in wood, even if it goes quite deep, is not that big deal unless it is in a structural component - and even then often well within the margin of safety.

Sanding *will* ruin the finish. But due to location, that portion of the cabinet sides will almost certainly always be covered up by a hood. If someday you install a hood that does not cover the entire area that had previously been covered, there are a number of ways of hiding the damage.

Comment: Good points well made. I might return this glass one and get a metal one that will conform to the space without cracking.

Comment: While changing the unit is a very good solution, a jig for a router could give you a very clean groove in the cabinet that could get a dab of caulking when done. And fwiw, I’ve watched (with a mix of fascination and horror) my glass guy sand glass. If I needed glass sanded, I’d be calling him rather than trying to diy.

Comment: One last idea, and I’m not completely joking: try to wedge a stick that’s 600.2mm into the space. You might find the cabinets have a tiny bit of flex. (You would, of course, have to leave something there to maintain the spacing.)

Comment: I think @AloysiusDefenestrate last comment is the best way to go if you want to keep the glass version.  Essentially you're building stress relief into the enclosure.

Comment: Sanding the side off a cabinet is a huge, messy job that's probably not necessary here and certainly won't end up flat. I don't even consider it a last resort. It's a non-starter. Unless you outline how one go about this and re-finish it, this isn't really an answer.

Comment: As long as the area, especially below, is masked off well, this is not a big deal as it doesn't need to be perfect and will be covered so doesn't need to be refinished.

Comment: I'm not sure how it wouldn't need to be perfect. Unless you're carving out a shape specifically to fit the hood, much of this sanding would be visible. Do I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: It would be to specifically fit the hood. Assumptions: Hood sides have same thickness (whether 1/4" or 12" or anything in between) front to back; hood sides are at least as deep as the cabinets (i.e., matches front of cabinets or extends farther into the room): Mask (might need more than just tape like for painting, but same principle) above and below where the glass will be, sand in between.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Many moons ago, I worked at a place where part of a chemical analysis procedure involved making glass buttons (about 5 cm diameter) in some sort of melting chamber. The moulding lines/anomalies were then cleaned off using an abrasive wheel, the same sort as you'd use to sharpen a lathe tool. Only the sample prep technician was brave enough to do that, although he told us all it was easy.

Comment: @AndrewMorton And there is quite a difference between a 5 cm button that you can hold in your hand (or in a small clamp when working on it) and a big expensive cooktop hood.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact In the case of the analysis results of these glass buttons, several hundred thousands dollars in some cases. But still the same pucker factor ;)

Answer (score 28):

Any glass intended for a kitchen is almost certainly tempered. You cannot modify tempered glass. It will explode or disintegrate. Even if it's not, you're unlikely to be successful without specialized tools and training.

You also wouldn't go grinding away at the finished end of your cabinet. That would make a real mess with no easy remedy. Unless you perfectly match a depression to the shape of your new hood, you'll have to deal with surface prep (flat and smooth), stain color, finish sheen, etc. It's a real bag of worms if you expect a professional result like I would.

I think of a hood as an appliance, and of cabinets as part of the home. Almost any time I've visually modified cabinets, or doors, or trim to accommodate something less permanent (or someone had before me) I've regretted it. Instead, **look at shortening a cabinet from a hidden point**. There's often a filler strip at the corners of the room that could be reduced, or you could pull off a side that's sandwiched against another cabinet and mill that down.

Show us more context for better answers. It may be as simple as re-mounting the cabinets a little more snugly to the side.

Comment: +1 for bringing attention to tempered glass - if it's not tempered, it certainly should be, being at risk from condensing steam, even if too far from the hob to heat much in normal use.

Answer (score 14):

If the hood is this kind of arrangement, basically a pair of glass wings extending from a central machine .... my suggestion is **return it and buy something different**.

No matter what you do it's going to look awful.

There needs to be a wide gap, as shown here, between the hood and the cabinets so you can clean them both.  Otherwise you'll get black gunk forming in there that will be visible through the glass and difficult or impossible to clean.

Also ... these glass hoods develop a film of dust-caked-in-congealed-oil that is HIGHLY visible and needs to be cleaned, top, bottom, sides, and rear, constantly --- otherwise they look AWFUL.   All hoods have this but on most of them, you can't see the top and the bottom is hidden by the front wall.

If you do ANYTHING to modify the side walls of the cabinet ... sand them, use a router to grind a channel in them, replace them with thinner panels, smash them with hammers ... ANYTHING .... it will look awful.

Just don't.

[image]

Comment: +1 from me - I keep saying that those fancy-looking hoods (same for stainless-steel inverted trapesium shape ones) are meant to be placed on a clean wall, i.e. the one without cupboards or cabinets. In your case I would strongly consider adding another cupboard with an under-cupboard hood unit. Not only you solve the problem of the gunk collecting, you get some extra space as well. And if you decide for that, look for the hoods with air outlet on the side and guide a flexible air duct in the corner of the cupboard getting even more useful space inside.

Comment: In line with the above comment, "meant to be placed on a clean wall", perhaps the best modification to the adjacent cabinets would be to *remove them* and redecorate the entire surrounding wall in line with the design intent of this hood.  Too bad that's not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

There's mentions in other posts of all sorts of changes to the glass, squeezing it in, *temporarily* moving the cabinets, etc.

**Do not compress or attempt to modify the glass in any way**

The glass contains invisible, but carefully and balanced stresses within it; watch the 10s segment from the marked time here https://youtu.be/j16GD0xzkhk?t=126 to see a very high-level of how careful cooling during manufacturing causes these stresses, which give the glass its desirable properties, *but must remain balanced!*

You want to ensure you have not just enough, but *extra* space with the hood in-place to prevent expansions of the nearby wood (which happens a little naturally with changes temperature and moisture) and the glass hood itself (it will expand a little when heated by the oven) from adding any pressure to the glass

Consider

- cutting away part of the cabinet such that there is space for the hood (you may be able to route a line or deeply sand away material which will be covered by the hood with a little to spare); you could use something like a Dremel "Multi-Max" for this
- widening the space permanently by forcing the cabinets apart with some spreader [as partially mentioned in a comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/238834/how-can-i-fit-a-glass-cooktop-hood-into-a-space-thats-too-tight#comment462602_238878) .. however, you almost-certainly want a frame that you leave in place after installing the glass to keep the extra space with seasonal expansion
- returning the hood and obtaining a metal one instead, which may fit more nicely into your space (this may actually save you some time and money covering the unsightly back wall, or could be a topper which acts as the permanent spreading frame from suggestion 2 for your glass hood)

Answer (score 2):

Depending how handy you are, there's a few answers. Although other answers/comments touch on some of these, I'd like to recap to add my own comments to those, too.

I would also like to see pics of (1) **the hood itself**, perhaps slightly angled from above or below to get a sense of the 3D form, and (2) **the entire cupboard space**, like maybe a wide view, 600mm either side of the hood, to get a sense of context, and how rigid or truly fixed the cupboards are likely to be. It would help to add those to the question.

## Shaving the edge of the hood

As @isherwood says, stressing tempered glass (which this will be) is a dead end. It can't take it. But equally no need to take it to a glazier either (although definitely safest).

If you truly are missing just 1 - 2 mm of width, I'd buy a diamond faced wheel, and grind one or both edges myself. Low pressure from the tool, and use plenty of slightly diluted washing up liquid (USA: dish soap I think) or other cheap lubricant, in this case, rather than the more usual running water or light oil. (Squirt and smooth onto the surface before grinding). You can get cheap disposable dremel-style diamond faced 60-75mm wheels [like this](https://www.joom.com/en/products/5c0afc6b8b45130101c1ef80), online, larger will work better as a rule, easier to position and check its smooth.

You only need to shave a little off, and only up to about 30-35cm from the wall where it runs along the cupboard.  So from the front it will look untouched and retain its polish. Drag the wheel at a slight angle, so you're grinding not cutting, and so you don't dig in.

[image]

After you have the width right, run/grind the wheel again, this time at 30-45 degrees from both above and below, to ensure the newly shaped edges don't have sharp spurs at the top and bottom, as these might not fit (if the grind wasn't level), or could cut into the wood, or worst case may jam it.

A lightweight wheel like this has virtually no chance at all of cracking or stressing it, and can be used in any household drill.

## Flexing the wall of the cupboards

I'd be wary of flexing with a temporary wedge, as one suggestion said. Same reason as above - when you remove the wedge, there will be extra pressure on the glass - and the glass is angled which reduces its ability to handle pressure side to side (in effect its already got a "fold" in it, as well as low tolerance of stress).

If you are going to flex the sides, perhaps use some kind of material with nice rounded ends that can be left in place, if possible, against the wall.

But even then I have my doubts. The board that makes up the back of the cupboards internally/behind may be a problem, though hopefully not. Depends on the material (thin hardboard or actual wood sheet, and whether if it slots in a groove or is nailed/glued (which makes the 4 sides a bit more rigid).  They can be either.

That said, the cupboard sides may flex anyway but then I have a more serious concern - you dont want wood permamounted above a cooker, but at the same time any other material is hard to get to the exact width needed, and will prevent the hood lying flush to the wall. And also, more serious again, if you brace the back edges apart, the front edges (30 or so cm from the wall won't be braced apart and may retain their original spacing.

Overall don't like this idea.

## Move the cupboards

A millimeter isn't much, and they aren't plastered in place (from the photo).

Don't use a rubber mallet. Instead, if they have room to move at all, remove all internal shelves and put a 4x2 inch (100x50mm) piece of wood up against the side of the cupboard to spread the shock and prevent damage, and use a club hammer more towards the top where mounting is expected to be.

The pic gives the general idea, using a light piece of wood and lightweight hammer though. You want heavy hammer/mallet, so it can be hit relatively slowly and still transmit momentum/impulse/shock to the cupboard mount.

Also - important! - **the wood should be the full length, overlapping top and bottom corners, not just in the middle as I've shown,** so it moves the cupboard as a whole not just bends the side a bit.

[image]

Of course don't do this if the finish might be cracked by it. You'll have to judge that. It * shouldn't * ...... if its in decent condition.....

## Replace the hood

Easy solution if grinding and nudging across aren't options. As you say, metal distorts a bit easier and certainly with less risk.

Comment: I'd also be tempted to take a little off the glass.  You do need to keep it wet, and wear safety glasses.  Silicon carbide or aluminium oxide abrasives will work just as well on glass. If it's truly only 0.1mm I'd just use wet/dry paper (SiC) on a block of wood, by hand, starting with 180-240 grit, maybe going to 600 at the end

Comment: If as the OP states the amount is >1mm, simply slackening the wall cabinets fixing screws may be enough

Comment: Instead of hammering, might it be better to exert some pressure using a spreader?  Many "quick" clamps are reversible to act as spreaders.

Comment: Might be worth looking where the cabinet meets the wall; shave a bit of plasterboard?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Have you tried it?
Since you have already bought the hood you can just lift it in and try if it fits. Maybe your measurement is not entirely correct or the hood is a little bit smaller than promised.
If it is too tight a fit and its only about a few millimeters (and there is not a wall directly next to the cupboards) you can try to move them a tiny little bit.
Normally there is always a little wiggle room in the mounting of the cupboards. Empty the cupboards, loosen the screws a bit, push the cupboard to the side and fasten the screws again. Maybe even mount the hood while the cupboard is loose.

Before you start sanding the glass you should find a slightly smaller hood in exchange for the bigger one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd loosen the screws on the back wall of the cabinets and tap them away from the center point of your opening to see if they move.  If you can remove the left cabinet, look at the left side of that cabinet, there is usually only contact with the next cabinet at the face frame.  You could shave the face frame by 1/8" or so (3mm) as needed to give you a bit of movement. Use a plane for best results.  The longer the better. Enlarge the holes in the back wall of the cabinet and remount them to the wall using the existing holes in the wall.  Some cabinets are also fastened to the face-frame of the adjacent cabinet.  Tighten them up. Life is good.

Answer (score 0):

replace the end panels of the cabinet with thinner ones. if you only need a few millimeters that should do the trick.

Comment: This answer is comically oversimplified. Did you look at the detail involved with the gapped panels? What about wood, stain, and finish matching? Not to mention the challenge of taking apart a cabinet that's probably glued together.  I'd feel awkward suggesting such a massive undertaking with so few words.

Comment: those MDF cabinets are typically screwed together, but yeah if it's glued could be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on environmental conditions, consider running a dehumidifier and lowering the temperature in the room and the temperature of the glass. (This would work here in Florida...maybe...). That only solves the initial problem of fit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Even if this was to work, the resulting stress on the glass when things return to normal could lead to catastrophe.

Comment: @isherwood i definitely agree with you, but one problem at a time, right?